# Problem using Add key value in app.config of c# windows application

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the below in my app.config

```
<add key="InstanceID" value="HID\VID_413C&PID_3200\6&227E6ED3&0&0000" />
```

It shows error in app.config, what is the problem ? i want to use this value as string in my c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your special characters, example (`& = &amp;`).  I think that's the only problem character.

Comment: I dint get u, can u reframe the value  ?

Comment: replace every "&" with "&amp;"